# Why is len(self) throwing a RecursionError in aiohttp? A.k.a. Strange behaviour of the azure event hubs libary

Tags: python, azure-storage, azure-eventhub, aiohttp, azure-sdk-python

That's a weird one.

We have a RecursionError thrown by aiohttp:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/streams.py", line 169, in on_eof
    callback()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/client_reqrep.py", line 943, in _response_eof
    self._connection.release()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 171, in release
    self._key, self._protocol, should_close=self._protocol.should_close
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/client_proto.py", line 53, in should_close
    or len(self) > 0
```

But we cannot identify any code that would be recursing in our main code.

Pipfile:

```
azure-eventhub-checkpointstoreblob-aio = "*"
azure-eventhub-checkpointstoreblob = "*"
```

Locked versions are:

```
azure-eventhub = "==5.5.0"
aiohttp = "==3.7.4.post0"
azure-eventhub-checkpointstoreblob = "==1.1.4"
azure-eventhub-checkpointstoreblob-aio = "==1.1.4"
```

The above error occurs in the coroutine that azure-eventhub creates when recieving.
From the event hub libary we get a wrapper message for above error on loglevel warning:

```
EventProcessor instance '...' of eventhub 'usage-ingress' consumer group '$Default'. An error occurred while load-balancing and claiming ownership. The exception is RecursionError('maximum recursion depth exceeded'). Retrying after 11.889686314484639 seconds
```

**Recursion error on such a method??** I already looked up the code bits on the stacktrace and I am baffled.

Details about the Infrastructure:

Checkpointing is done on an Azure Storage Datalake Gen2 with Hirarchical Filesystem.
Libary built in request logging for the requests to storage show a 200 for the ownership and checkpoint requests but also the message

```
"No body was attached to the request"
```

Our service started to get slow (1-5 Events per hour throughput on the reciever with 100k Events coming into the Eventhub) without any code change or redeployment.

We already suspected eventhub service throttling but no throttled requests on the metrics.
Also no throttling on the Data Lake. Except a really long access time on the checkpoints folder that is created on the filesystem by the eventhub libary. Access tier is hot.

I am completely clueless on why this is happening. I hope somebody has an idea.
Cheers

**EDIT**:
Related to this:

```
"level": "ERR", "message": "Exception in eof callback", "threadid": 140306312525568, "processid": 10, "channel": "aiohttp.internal", "exception": "RecursionError", "stacktrace": "  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/streams.py\", line 169, in on_eof\n    callback()\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/client_reqrep.py\", line 943, in _response_eof\n    self._connection.release()\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py\", line 167, in release\n    self._notify_release()\n"
```

**EDIT#2**:
In response to Adam:

```
Jun 24, 2021 @ 01:16:21.628 Request URL: 'https://<storage>.blob.core.windows.net/<resGroup>?restype=REDACTED&comp=REDACTED&prefix=REDACTED&marker=REDACTED&include=REDACTED'   INF  -   -  azure.core.pipeline.policies.http_logging_policy
    Jun 24, 2021 @ 01:16:21.629 Request method: 'GET'   INF  -   -  azure.core.pipeline.policies.http_logging_policy
    Jun 24, 2021 @ 01:16:21.629     'Authorization': 'REDACTED' INF  -   -  azure.core.pipeline.policies.http_logging_policy
    Jun 24, 2021 @ 01:16:21.629 No body was attached to the request INF  -   -  azure.core.pipeline.policies.http_logging_policy
    Jun 24, 2021 @ 01:16:21.629 Request headers:    INF  -   -  azure.core.pipeline.policies.http_logging_policy
    Jun 24, 2021 @ 01:16:21.629     'x-ms-version': 'REDACTED'  INF  -   -  azure.core.pipeline.policies.http_logging_policy
    Jun 24, 2021 @ 01:16:21.629     'Accept': 'application/xml' INF  -   -  azure.core.pipeline.policies.http_logging_policy
    Jun 24, 2021 @ 01:16:21.629     'x-ms-date': 'REDACTED' INF  -   -  azure.core.pipeline.policies.http_logging_policy
    Jun 24, 2021 @ 01:16:21.629     'x-ms-client-request-id': '05acf018-d479-11eb-af7d-a2f51e4cb2c7'    INF  -   -  azure.core.pipeline.policies.http_logging_policy
    Jun 24, 2021 @ 01:16:21.629     'User-Agent': 'azsdk-python-storage-blob/12.7.1 Python/3.8.10 (Linux-5.4.0-1047-azure-x86_64-with-glibc2.28)'   INF  -   -  azure.core.pipeline.policies.http_logging_policy
    Jun 24, 2021 @ 01:16:24.924 Response status: 200    INF  -   -  azure.core.pipeline.policies.http_logging_policy
    Jun 24, 2021 @ 01:16:24.924     'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked'  INF  -   -  azure.core.pipeline.policies.http_logging_policy
    Jun 24, 2021 @ 01:16:24.924 Exception in eof callback   ERR   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/streams.py", line 169, in on_eof
    callback()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/client_reqrep.py", line 943, in _response_eof
    self._connection.release()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 171, in release
    self._key, self._protocol, should_close=self._protocol.should_close
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/client_proto.py", line 53, in should_close
    or len(self) > 0
    RecursionError  aiohttp.internal
    Jun 24, 2021 @ 01:16:24.924 Response headers:   INF  -   -  azure.core.pipeline.policies.http_logging_policy
    Jun 24, 2021 @ 01:16:24.925     'x-ms-version': 'REDACTED'  INF  -   -  azure.core.pipeline.policies.http_logging_policy
    Jun 24, 2021 @ 01:16:24.925     'Date': 'Wed, 23 Jun 2021 23:16:24 GMT' INF  -   -  azure.core.pipeline.policies.http_logging_policy
    Jun 24, 2021 @ 01:16:24.925     'Content-Type': 'application/xml'   INF  -   -  azure.core.pipeline.policies.http_logging_policy
    Jun 24, 2021 @ 01:16:24.925     'Server': 'Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0'    INF  -   -  azure.core.pipeline.policies.http_logging_policy
    Jun 24, 2021 @ 01:16:24.925     'x-ms-request-id': '57d01bb6-e01e-0019-7185-68c5ca000000'   INF  -   -  azure.core.pipeline.policies.http_logging_policy
    Jun 24, 2021 @ 01:16:24.925     'x-ms-client-request-id': 'f789fce2-d478-11eb-80e0-a2f51e4cb2c7'
```

Seems like the error is caused when hitting some kind of eof in the request phase.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you have versioning enabled for the storage account?

Comment: Wish if it would, then there would be a thing to start from. Sadly, versioning is disabled.

Comment: What about soft delete?   That also has been known to slow down enumerating containers.   Though I just checked (with my limited Python skills) and it looks like we're doing the right thing to not cause unnecessary deletions.   I've asked the folks working on the Python version of the SDK to take a look at your question and see if they can assist better than I.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. We don't have soft delete enabled.

Comment: The aiohttp is used for performing storage related operation, e.g. claiming ownership of a partition.
Depending on the logging, the error occurred when the sdk was doing [load-balance and claiming partitions](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/main/sdk/eventhub/azure-eventhub/azure/eventhub/aio/_eventprocessor/event_processor.py#L373-L383).

Could you kindly provide more logging info with me so that I could narrow down the function call that triggers the error? you could set the logging level to INFO to have a comprehensive logging.

btw, how often does the error happen?

Comment: This error currently happens constantly, our service is impeded because of this error :/ Comprehensive logs from Loglevel info in the edit.

Comment: I'm sorry about that and thanks for the logging. Given the info, it seems to be the [list_ownership](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/main/sdk/eventhub/azure-eventhub-checkpointstoreblob-aio/azure/eventhub/extensions/checkpointstoreblobaio/_blobstoragecsaio.py#L168) causing the error. How does your container directory structure look like in the storage? and does the error happen when you're using a normal storage blob (no ADSL enabled)? I can't reproduce the issue on windows but I noticed that you're working on a linux machine, so I'll try to reproduce it on a linux machine.

Comment: Reproducing in a "normal" azure storage will be a bit tricky for us as we have to change our deployments for that one. Location: account / container / usage-ingress / $default / ownership

Comment: I could not reproduce the issue on linux..
could you help use the [snippets](https://gist.github.com/yunhaoling/6e4f0ad8b733ed0dd3046687aecbdcd2) to verify if calling the list_ownership method alone would trigger the error?

btw, the config of blob storage I used is as following:
Account kind: StorageV2 (general purpose v2)
Location: West US
Data Lake Storage:
Hierarchical namespace Enabled
Default access tier Hot
Blob public access Enabled
Blob soft delete Disabled
Container soft delete Disabled
Versioning Disabled
Change feed Disabled
NFS v3 Disabled

Is there any difference?

Comment: Effectively the issue could be resolved with increasing the partition count on the Event Hubs and then manually deleting the ownership blob. Thanks for your time! Still pretty strange to see such recursion errors here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my problem was resolved through increasing the partition count on the Event Hubs and the manually deleting the ownership blob for that Event Hub.

Still pretty strange, but I could not come up with a clear repro of this error.

Comment: I'm glad you find a solution for it! Don't hesitate to reach out to the team in the [azure-sdk-for-python repo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues) if you find the problem is still disturbing you :) we're always glad to help